# Не получается добавить action внутри map

Tags: reactjs, redux

Всем привет. Помогите новичку в `redux`.

Почему в таком подходе приложение ломается выводя ошибку:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
renderListHandler(){
     return this.props.heroes.map(hero => {
            return (
                <div key={hero.name}>
                    <h4 onClick={this.props.onClickOneOfVariant}>{hero.name}</h4>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }

renderImagesHandler(){
        const heroes = this.props.heroes;//Добавляем переменную героев чтобы внизу использовать дважды
        const image = ~~(Math.random() * heroes.length); //Берем случайную картинку из героев 
        return heroes[image].src; //Возвращаем картинку
    }
render(){
    const arr = this.renderListHandler(); //Возвращаем весь массив суда
    const shuffledArr = shuffle(arr); //Shuffle простой алгоритм чтобы перемещать массив ничего серьезного
    return (
         <Container className="h-100">
             <img src={this.renderImagesHandler()} alt="secret" /> //Показываем тут одну случайную картинку
             {shuffledArr} //Показываем тут перемещанный массив героев
         </Container>
    )
}
```

Это часть с `Redux`

```
const mapStateToProps =  state => {
    return {
        heroes: state.nameAndImage,
        ctr:state.counter
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onClickOneOfVariant:() => dispatch({type:"TRUEVARIANT"})
    };
};
```

Это `reducer`

```
const initialState = {
    counter:0,
    nameAndImage:data
}

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if(action.type === "TRUEVARIANT"){
        return {
            counter:state.counter + 1,
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

А data к нему приходит вот так

```
export const data = [{
    src: Vers,
    name: "Captain Marvel"
}, {
    src: Venom,
    name: "Venom"
}, {
    src: Thanos,
    name: "Thanos"
}]
```

`src` внутри `data` это картинки которые я подключил указав имя всем

пример: `import Vers from "../assets/marvel/vers.jpg";`

И использовал этот `Vers` внутри `data`

Без этой `onClickOneOfVariant` событии все работает идеально.

Но если его добавить страница загружается но при клике на один из `h4`  выводит ошибку

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Что я делаю неправильно подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: this.props.heroes не массив?

Comment: Потому что в пропсе `heroes` - лежит `undefined`, отсюда и ошибка. Пропишите через `defaultProps` значение по умолчанию, пустой массив и будет норм. В случае с ридаксом проинициализирейте переменную в пропсе пустым массивом изначально.

Comment: @DenisBubnov а можно по подробнее?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну как сказать это массив который я сам создал что то типо JSON только js.В одном из файлов возвращаю массив который содержит обьектов.И этот файл впихнул в reducer чтобы работать с ним.

Comment: В случае с Redux - нужно начальное значение задать, так сказать `initialState` в редьюсере. В большинстве примеров будет этот начальный стейт. Про `defaultProps` можете глянуть тут: [Typechecking With PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Comment: распечатайте его сожержимое и приложите в ввопрос

Comment: Самая простая правка в вашем случае такая: `heroes: state.nameAndImage || [],`

Comment: @DenisBubnov к сожалению последний способ не сработал

Comment: @StrangerintheQ готово добавил

Comment: если вот тут renderListHandler(){ console.log(this.props.heroes); ...} поставить лог, что выводит?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это уже я проверял выводит список (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: В редьюсер внесите правку. При экшне `TRUEVARIANT` вот такой результат верните: `return { ...state,
            counter:state.counter + 1,
        }`

Comment: @DenisBubnov спасибо большое.Так без него же должно было работать.Может  в новой версии редакс уже невозможно менять стейт immutably .Напишите ответ приму +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание на код вашего редьюсера:

```
const initialState = {
    counter: 0,
    nameAndImage: data
}

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === "TRUEVARIANT") {
        return {
            counter: state.counter + 1,
        }
    }

    return state;
}
```

Первоначальный стейт (когда экшн не с типом `TRUEVARIANT`), будет возвращен нормальным и полным, такой:

```
counter: 0,
nameAndImage: data
```

Однако в случае с типом `TRUEVARIANT` результат будет таким:

```
counter: state.counter + 1
```

То есть при обращение к пропсе `nameAndImage` внутри компонента будет `undefined`, потому что эта переменная не проинициализирована. Поэтому необходимо внести вот такую правку:

```
return {
  ...state,
  counter: state.counter + 1
}
```

Так называемый [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) помогает нам скопировать объект `state` в результат (копирует собственные перечисляемые свойства данного объекта `state` в новый объект.), а строка `counter: state.counter + 1` перезапишет значение из прошлого `state` на новое.

Comment: аааа так вот оно в чем было проблема ..Спасибо огромное за помощь .

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы избежать подобных ошибок рекомендую использовать комбинацию редьюсеров в вашем roorReducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { data } from 'somewhere-in-your-project';


const counterReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    if (action.type === "TRUEVARIANT") {
        return state + 1;
    }

    return state;
};

const nameAndImageReducer = (state = data, action) => {
    if (action.type === "TRUEVARIANT") {
        // возвращать данные для узла nameAndImage
    }

    return state;
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    counter: counterReducer,
    nameAndImage: nameAndImageReducer,
});


export default rootReducer;
```

Таким образом вы работаете с каждым узлом стэйта по-отдельности, минимизировав шансы затронуть соседние узлы и избежите ошибки.